# Segfault with Laravel - how to debug?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having a bit of an issue with my Laravel install—everything works fine with no errors until I run a `php artisan optimize`. When I `php artisan serve` after that, the server crashes immediately after I try to load any page. I tried serving it with `php -S` and got the same crash (though this time I got a segmentation fault logged). 
If I run `php artisan clear-compiled`, everything works again as expected.

I'm pretty unfamiliar with apache and PHP in general - can someone suggest how to go about debugging this or what the issue might be?

(I just ran it again with php artisan serve, and this time I got `zend_mm_heap corrupted` before crashing)

Comment: This is not a Laravel issue, it's a PHP issue. Running `php -S` (which is what `php artisan serve` does) starts up PHP's "internal" web server. This is apparently what's crashing. Perhaps you can update your version of PHP?

Comment: I'm using MAMP with PHP 5.5.10 -- quite new I think and I haven't had any issues so far until I tried optimizing. While I understand the error itself is in PHP, I feel like the optimization is generating some faulty code. Then again, I have a very basic understanding of how this works.

Comment: It should not be possible to segfault at all with PHP (unless doing something with an extension that permits non-permitted low-level operations e.g. with memory allocation). It is very likely to be a bug with PHP or PHP in combination with your system. Would you add your PHP extension list to your post?

Comment: PHP 5.5.14 is available, try that?

Comment: `php artisan optimize` generates the `bootstrap/compiled.php` file, which basically includes a bunch of code for the framework. If the application is running before the optimize, there shouldn't be an issue after, since it's the same code - unless it's an abnormally large file (mine is about 10k lines long, which doesn't seem too big).

Comment: The list of my extensions is here: http://pastebin.com/YUJ5112m#
I'll give the update a try. I'll also try disabling all those caching extensions, I enabled those a while back to test some things out and they might be conflicting.

Comment: Posted my fix below — I really can't explain what the issue was but turning off OPCache in MAMP options fixed it. Thanks anyhow!
(If you do have an explanation though, I'd definitely love to hear it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue — was something pretty silly. Fired up MAMP, went to the options, and turned off OPCache. (I use the MAMP php as the default on my system).

Some sort of conflict there, I can't explain it but the issue is gone.

Comment: I turned off of XCache. Same result. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have to turn off OPCache. OPCache does its own optimizations and dramatically improves PHP's performance. By turning this off to get the compiled class to work, you're robbing Peter to pay Paul. Something is likely wrong with the way Laravel generates that compiled file, or an OPCache setting needs to be adjusted to accomodate that large file